# TableLayout alignment with icon

Tags: android, icons, alignment, tablelayout

Here is my XML. 
I want to align the icon to the left and the text should appear right next to the icon, with some space, like you see elsewhere.  But the text is showing up in the center. (or right aligned to the 2nd column, in two column layout)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main_scroll"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true" >

  <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="2"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/events_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="5dip">
              <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02" 
                  android:src="@drawable/event_icon"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                  android:layout_margin="5dp">
              </ImageView>
              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View Events"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textSize="21dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
         </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

This is how it displays:

```
    [  *             View Events        ]
```

- is the icon. I want to display like this.

  ```
  [  *  View Events                   ]
  ```

Comment: What's the size of that icon? There's a good chance it's being scaled down without the bounds actually wrapping the result. Try adding [`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) to the `ImageView`.

Comment: Did not work :-( Size is 16X16px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `android:stretchColumns="2"` to `android:stretchColumns="1"` because column index starts with **0**. So if you only have two columns then the second column stands at index **1**.

Comment: It was 1 initially. Since that did not work, I tried 2 to see if it changes. No change to layout. The problem still exists.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of using a separate column for your icon, why dont you simply use left-drawable to your TextView? it will cause one less view per row

Comment: Can you pls explain? Maybe can you write it? Thanks!